# How to suppress display of *some* comments in Cucumber feature file?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, comments

I have some comments in feature files that refer to the file itself (like Emacs local variables, or a licence block) or are included to guide  future developers.  *Meta*-comments, if you will.  Is there any way to keep them from being included in the `cucumber` run output?  In days gone by, in other languages with comment extractors, you could do something like this:

```rb
#--
# This a meta-comment for helping developers edit this file.
# it should *not* appear in the output of a run.
#++

# This feature does
# diddly-squat, but the comment should
# appear in the run output
Feature: tell me about it
```

I *suspect* that putting meta-comments at the end, after all the Cucumber instructions, would keep them from being extracted/displayed, but that doesn't help for cases in which they need to appear mid-file.

Thanks for any suggestions, answers, and/or pointers to docco about this that I've failed to find so far!

Comment: Which cucumber are you using?

Comment: You could suppress what ever the thing is in Cucumber that generates the output and put in your own. But probably easier to add a preprocessor in your build system that strips the meta-comments.

Comment: `cucumber-3.1.2` with Ruby